# gradle - how to declare a dependency of a jar in a jar

Tags: ivy, gradle

Using gradle, I am consuming a build from an archiva repository.  One of the jars (`javax.jms_1.1.0.200810061358.jar`) has the following content:

```
about.html
about_files
LICENSE.txt
jms.jar
META-INF
MANIFEST.MF
```

The jar I need is actually the jms.jar inside this `javax.jms_1.1.0.200810061358.jar`

The only way I've been able to consume this jar is by pulling jms.jar
out of the repository's `javax.jms_1.1.0.200810081358.jar` and saving it
to the file system and consuming it via:

```
repositories { flatDir: my_dir_with_jms.jar_in_it}
```

someone on the gradle list suggested using an Ivy packager resolver.

I looked at this [link](http://ivyroundup.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/files/packager.html) and was
left very confused.  I do have other ivy resolvers set up like this:

```
addIvyPattern 'http://archivaserver:8080/archiva/repository/osgi-internal/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy_[revision].xml'
   addArtifactPattern
"http://archivaserver:8080/archiva/repository/osgi-official/[organisation]/[organisation]/[module]_[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"
```

Anyone know of a good solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolving a dependency inside a dependency would require the use of the ivy [packager resolver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/packager.html).

I've never configured the package resolver from within Gradle, but I think it would work something like the following (Referencing [webpage](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.programming.tools.gradle.user/4982))

```
repositories {
    add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.packager.PackagerResolver()) {
        name = 'local Ivy packagers'

        buildRoot = file("${gradle.gradleUserHomeDir}/packager/build")
        resourceCache = file("${gradle.gradleUserHomeDir}/packager/cache")

        addIvyPattern      "file:///${project.rootDir}/ivy/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"
        addArtifactPattern "file:///${project.rootDir}/ivy/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/packager.xml"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.myorg', name: 'jms', version: '1.1.0.200810061358'
}
```

The resolver requires the following files for the declared dependency:

```
ivy/org.myorg/jms/1.1.0.200810061358/ivy.xml
ivy/org.myorg/jms/1.1.0.200810061358/packager.xml
```

### ivy.xml

Describes the module and in this case declares what artifacts are published:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="org.myorg" module="jms" revision="1.1.0.200810061358" status="release"/>

    <publications>
        <artifact name="jms" type="jar"/>
    </publications>

</ivy-module>
```

### packager.xml

Describes where the enclosing archive is located and instructions on how to extract jms.jar:

```
<packager-module version="1.0">

    <resource dest="archive" url="http://archivaserver:8080/archiva/repository/??/javax.jms_1.1.0.200810061358.jar" sha1="????"/>

    <build>
        <move file="archive/jms.jar" tofile="artifacts/jars/jms.jar"/>
    </build>

</packager-module>
```

The content under the **build** tag is used to generate an ANT script. For more details read the "Packaging instructions" section of the [ivy documentation](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/packager.html)