# How would I publish a java protobuf jar to my nexus repo?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, nexus

On my build server I'm planning on generating a JAR file from my proto spec. I'd like to ideally publish that jar to my nexus server so my Java projects can pull that dependency down like any other dependency. How should I structure that on the build server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified which build tool you're using.

One option is to upload the file using the Maven command-line:

- [Upload artifacts to Nexus, without Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029532/upload-artifacts-to-nexus-without-maven/4036706#4036706)

A second option is to use the Nexus repository upload UI.

(In both cases the Maven module POM will be generated for you).