# Create checksum and pom for maven repo

Tags: maven, ant, pom.xml, checksum

i have my Java application with maven distribution, and i need to create check sum e pom file for the jar in my repository.

I use Net-Beans to develop.
Can someone help me?

Comment: What do you need this for? Are you referring to deployment to a remote artifact repository manager (such as Nexus, Artifactory, Archiva)? If so, then the checkums will be generated for you once you execute `mvn deploy`. (Of course, you will need to have proper `settings.xml` and `<distributionManagement/>` set up in your `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/). Ivy understands how to download dependencies from Maven repositories and it can also be configured to publish artifacts there as well:

[how to publish 3rdparty artifacts with ivy and nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111831/how-to-publish-3rdparty-artifacts-with-ivy-and-nexus/5115447#5115447)

It's an approach worth exploring if your looking for a pure ANT solution. You should also consider simply calling Maven to publish the jar as well. It has the ability to generate a POM on the fly.

[Upload artifacts to Nexus, without Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029532/upload-artifacts-to-nexus-without-maven/4036706#4036706)