# how to upload ear files into nexus for non maven project

Tags: jenkins, nexus

[currently we are using manual upload through GUI of nexus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPMfM.png)I have a Java project (which is not a maven project means no POM.xml) and SVN repo and jenkins(using ant script for build) for CI. The build process creating War and Ear files locally in jenkins workspace. I want to upload this EAR to Nexus repository. It doesn't use Maven for builds. And I'd rather not introduce Maven/POM files just to get files into Nexus.

So, what's the best (or any reasonable) way to upload build artifacts to a Nexus repository without Maven?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload artifacts to Nexus, without Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029532/upload-artifacts-to-nexus-without-maven)

Comment: i have tried ivy:publish and mvn: deploy but NO luck. For both of them its showing access to URL refused by the server: Unauthorized

Comment: @MarkO'Connor tried those solution :(

Comment: If it's a 401 error then you're using the wrong credentials.

Comment: Refer the Stackoverflow link for answer [Uploading war file to Nexus using jenkins job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669368/uploading-war-file-to-nexus-using-jenkins-job)