# Uploading war file to Nexus using jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, nexus

I have a zip file which contains version like this `xxx_1.2.3.zip` now i created one `jenkins` job which will run and upload the zip in nexus using `build.xml`.

My question is i want to unzip and find the war file and want to upload zip and war file to `nexus`.i am able to do using below code but it is not storing the `war` file with its original name artifact id and group id.Zip contains `yyy.war`.when i stores to nexus it should upload like yyy_1.2.3.war.But is is storing as `xxx-jenkins` build `number.war`.

Please help .Thanks in advance.

```
 unzip ${xxx_ReleaseVersion}
 echo "<project> <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion><groupId>zzz</groupId> <artifactId>xxx</artifactId> <version>${BUILD_NUMBER}  </version>       <packaging>pom</packaging> </project>" > pom.xml
 echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" standalone=\"no\"?>
 <project basedir=\".\" name=\"xxx\" default=\"deploy\"    xmlns:artifact=\"antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant\">
 <artifact:pom id=\"mypom\" file=\"pom.xml\" />
 <target name=\"deploy\">       
 <artifact:deploy file=\"pom.xml\">
 <remoteRepository url=\"https://URL/nexus/content/repositories/xxx\">
    <authentication username=\"xxxx\" password=\"1234\" />
 </remoteRepository>
 <pom refid=\"mypom\"/> 
 <attach file=\"${xxx_ReleaseVersion}\" type=\"zip\"/> " > build.xml
 find . -type f -name "*.war" -exec echo "<attach file=\"{}\"type=\"war\"/> "   >> build.xml \;
 echo "</artifact:deploy>
 </target>
 </project>  " >> build.xml

  pwd
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Nexus-Artifact-Uploader](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Nexus+Artifact+Uploader) plugin in Jenkins

This plugin goal is to upload artifacts generated from non-maven projects to Nexus. This plugin now supports Nexus-2.x & Nexus-3.x.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Nexus-Artifact-Uploader plugin but you have to change the version id manually every time you want build

Comment: A bit more details might be helpful. Like a link to the plugin, and a quick summary of how to use it. Right now, your answer reads more like a mediocre comment.

Comment: when you install plugin sonatype nexus NEXUS PLATFORM PLUGIN ,first configure your nexus server under global tool configuration section and then you will see an option Nexus Repository Manager Publisher under builds section , give your repository details and save

Comment: Dont put such information into comments - improve your answer instead!