# Upload non java artifacts to nexus 3.1.0-04

Tags: file-upload, nexus3

I want to be able to upload a non java artifact to hosted nexus3 repository. For this I used the curl commands described in this link [uploadToNexus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029532/upload-artifacts-to-nexus-without-maven), but it worked only for nexus 2. I noticed also that we can create groovy script, upload them to nexus and run them ([RestApi](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/scripting.html), but I'm not sure if we can create a groovy script to upload artifacts. Is there a groovy script giving this possiblity ? I'm wondering also if there is any non maven alternative to the maven deploy plugin ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a non Java artifact, you might look at using our RAW repository, depending on what it is. However, if you for sure want to use a Maven repository, the good news is you can :)

Assuming you have a fairly normal local setup, go with something akin to this. The big change between Repository Manager 2 and 3 is that the endpoints changed, which is why the old commands are not working for you.

```
curl -v -u admin:admin123 --upload-file file.jar http://localhost:8081/repository/releases/org/foo/1.0/file.jar
```