# Ant Build: Extract class files from a Ivy dependency war file in the class folder

Tags: ant, jenkins, build-process, ivy

I have a project with a dependency to some other Java classes from another project.
In eclipse the two projects are running without any errors.

Now I want to build the project with the dependency with Jenkins and Ant.

I get the dependency from Ivy with this config:

```
<publications>
    <artifact name="${version.name}" type="war" ext="war"/>
</publications>

<dependencies>
    <dependency org="de.company.sh" name="rest-db" rev="latest.integration"/>
</dependencies>
```

The retrieve in the build.xml:

```
<!-- retrieve dependencies from ivy -->
<target name="retrieve" depends="prepare, prepare.productive, prepare.beta">
    <!-- Fetch parameters from properties -->
    <property file="build.properties" />
    <!-- Resolve module -->
    <ivy:resolve file="ivy.xml" />
    <!-- Retrieve dependencies -->
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${build}/deps/[organization]/[module]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
</target>
```

The console log from Jenkins:

```
[ivy:resolve] Apr 24, 2013 1:42:06 PM   org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor selectAuthScheme
[ivy:resolve] INFO: Basic authentication scheme selected
[ivy:resolve] downloading    http://localhost:7080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/de/company/sh/rest-db/1.0.3269/wars/rest-db-1.0.3269.war ...
```

**Up to this point everything is ok**

But now I have the problem that I can´t include the class files from the war file.
Folder structure from the war file to the relevant class files:
rest-db-1.0.3269.war\WEB-INF\classes\de\company\sh...

Here are my attempts, with no success :-(

```
<!-- create war file from java classes -->
<target name="war" depends="compile">


    <!-- Move rest-db where it is needed
    <war destfile="${build}/lib/rest-db.war" webxml="WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <zipfileset dir="${build}/classes" includes="**/*.class"/>
    </war>
     -->
    <!-- -->
    <zip destfile="${build}/deps/de.company.sh/rest-db" basedir="${build}" update="true" />

    <!-- Copy all necessary Spring libraries -->
    <copy todir="${build}/lib">
        <!-- All files directly located in the lib/ directory -->
        <fileset dir="${lib}">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
```

...

```
    <!-- Move rest-db where it is needed
    <copy todir="${build}/classes">
        <fileset dir="${build}/deps/de.company.sh/rest-db">
            <include name="*.*" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
     -->
```

I hope you have some brilliant suggestions for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to declare a dependency on artifacts inside an artifact already downloaded using ivy?

Perhaps the packager resolver is where you need to look. Powerful although a bit complicated to setup.

For examples see:

- [ivy dependency on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987108/ivy-dependency-on-external-jar/7464028#7464028)
- [gradle - how to declare a dependency of a jar in a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445696/gradle-how-to-declare-a-dependency-of-a-jar-in-a-jar/3454359#3454359)