# Ant Target to Expand Archives of Dependency

Tags: maven, ant, ivy, ant-contrib

I have an Ant/Ivy build process that I am trying to improve. I need to resolve dependencies and then extract them to a particular folder.

The dependencies resolve to a `$(build_root)/dependency/downloads/[configuration]/[artifactId]/[version]/` location and this works fine. I end up with a `.pom` and a `.tar.bz2` file in that location.

What I would like to do is have a bit more control over the extraction of the dependency's `.tar.bz2` to a directory.  We're basically trying to prevent conflicts for a dependency's `lib` and `inc`  by controlling how and where the extraction of the `.tar.bz2` output occurs.

We currently do this by resolving all the dependencies, and then having a target to expand the archives blindly.

Our resolve step looks like:

```
<target name="resolve">
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${dependency.dir}/[conf]/[artifact]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" conf="*" />
    <condition property="archive.dir.present">
        <resourceexists>
            <file file="${dependency.dir}"/>
        </resourceexists>
    </condition>
    <antcall if:set="archive.dir.present" target="expand-archives"/>
</target>
```

Note the separate call to the "expand-archives" target, which looks like:

```
<target name="expand-archives" description="Expand your Dependency Archives!">
    <for param="file">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="${dependency.dir}" includes="**/*.tar.bz2"/>
        </path>
        <sequential>
            <bunzip2 src="@{file}" dest="${dependency.dir}" />
        </sequential>
    </for>
    <!-- Follow the bunzip2 by the tar command to extract the tarball -->
    <for param="file">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="${dependency.dir}" includes="**/*.tar"/>
        </path>
        <sequential>
            <echo message="Processing: @{file}"/>
            <exec executable="tar" failonerror="true">
                <arg value="-C"/>
                <arg value="${dependency.dir}"/>
                <arg value="-xvf"/>
                <arg value="@{file}"/>
            </exec>
        </sequential>
    </for>
</target>
```

What I would love to have is the `dest="${dependency.dir}` have a dependency's artifactID appended to it.

Is there any way to get the `[artifact]` information from the retrieve and pass that into the `expand-archives` target?

Thank you

Comment: I have continued to do research and it appears that I should use `Triggers` to resolve my issue. I'll update once I get it working. 

Further suggestions/tips are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you have dependencies on files located within archives, perhaps you should investigate the [packager resolver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/packager.html) in ivy.

This resolver is designed to download + extract archives and then use an ANT snippet to decide which files within you want to depend on. At first glance complicated, but once understood very powerful.

The following example shows how to depend on a jar, contained inside a downloadable ".tar.gz" archive:

- [ivy dependency on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987108/ivy-dependency-on-external-jar/7464028#7464028)