# Resolving Dependency from Github using Ivy.xml

Tags: java, ivy

I have a github repo that I created a Release for.  While creating the release I manually added a .jar file. Lets call it exampleLibrary.jar
This would be github.com/MyExampleRepo/Releases

I have a project I want to add a dependency for to use this exampleLibrary.jar file I added in my release v1.0

This project using Ivy.xml for resolving dependencies.

To get the jar from github using maven with pom.xml I imagine it would look something like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.User</groupId>
    <artifactId>Repo name</artifactId>
    <version>Release tag</version>
</dependency>
```

How would I do this using Ivy.xml? This is what I have tried:

```
<dependency org="com.github" name="MyExampleRepo" rev="v1.0"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ivy dependency on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987108/ivy-dependency-on-external-jar)

Comment: Most dependency managers (Gradle, Maven, Ivy, etc.) will have a much easier time consuming a library if you publish it to a Maven repository like Maven Central or Jcenter.